# A method to match narrow bands from in-situ spectrometer with Landsat-8 central band

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, landsat-8, resampling, reflectance

Is there a way to resample Landsat-8 bands to match different bands from a spectrophotometer. I'm doing atmospheric correction, comparing in-situ reflectance measurements performed using 10-nm wide spectral bands with reflectance from satellite images with much broader bands.

In-situ visible bands are for example: 441.8nm, 491.6nm, 530.5nm and 555.4nm; whereas Landsat-8's corresponding bands are 443nm, 482nm, 561nm and 655nm respectively.

I know ENVI can be used but don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

What you said about 443nm etc. are only central wavelength.  The reflectance of one channel of Landsat 8 is not only related to the central wavelength like 443nm. In other words, the band reflectance is a weighted average value. If you have the in-situ data with high spectral resolution, you can convolve it with the spectral response functions of Landsat 8, then band reflectance is derived.  However, what you want to do is just to interpolate the in-situ spectrum to the expected band central wavelength that is sepcification of landsat 8.

Comment: Ok @ JZH. How can I go about this please? Not sure if it's the right approach, I was trying ENVI spectral resampling but was getting an error that output wavelength are outside the range of input wavelength ... Perhaps I'm missing something - I used a text file containing reflectance values from in-situ visible bands.